# Sudden crash with React Native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a react native app that consume information from a web service. I have a bug when the app is loaded the first time after a couple of hours and nothing is showed in the Chrome console. The app crashes and the next time it works fina. I've not found any useful information in the Internet. This is what the logcat tell me

```
03-26 11:23:37.219 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "attendees" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
03-26 11:23:37.392 24853 24853 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@fe3592d
03-26 11:23:37.393 24853 24853 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ec6de62
03-26 11:23:37.408 24853 24888 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextShadowNode
03-26 11:23:37.476 24853 24853 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@958b7dc
03-26 11:23:37.579 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS: action @ 11:23:37.576 SET_DEVICE_CONNECTION
03-26 11:23:37.582 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS: '%c prev state', 'color: #9E9E9E; font-weight: bold', { listAllPublicEvents: [],
03-26 11:23:37.582 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS:   setCurrentEvent: {},
03-26 11:23:37.582 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS:   setCurrentEventRow: -1,
03-26 11:23:37.582 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS:   setDeviceConnection: true }
03-26 11:23:37.582 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS: '%c action', 'color: #03A9F4; font-weight: bold', { type: 'SET_DEVICE_CONNECTION', isConnected: true }
03-26 11:23:37.583 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS: '%c next state', 'color: #4CAF50; font-weight: bold', { listAllPublicEvents: [],
03-26 11:23:37.583 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS:   setCurrentEvent: {},
03-26 11:23:37.583 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS:   setCurrentEventRow: -1,
03-26 11:23:37.583 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS:   setDeviceConnection: true }
03-26 11:23:37.583 24853 24887 I ReactNativeJS: —— log end ——
03-26 11:23:38.067 24853 24858 I art     : Do partial code cache collection, code=24KB, data=30KB
03-26 11:23:38.068 24853 24858 I art     : After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=30KB
03-26 11:23:38.068 24853 24858 I art     : Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
03-26 11:23:38.124 24853 24887 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xcdb800cc in tid 24887 (mqt_js)
03-26 11:23:38.125   464   464 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=24853 uid=10239 gid=10239 tid=24887
03-26 11:23:38.212 24900 24900 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-26 11:23:38.212 24900 24900 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus3/OnePlus3T:7.0/NRD90M/01122128:user/release-keys'
03-26 11:23:38.212 24900 24900 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-26 11:23:38.212 24900 24900 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
03-26 11:23:38.213 24900 24900 F DEBUG   : pid: 24853, tid: 24887, name: mqt_js  >>> com.attendees <<<
03-26 11:23:38.213 24900 24900 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xcdb800cc
03-26 11:23:38.213 24900 24900 F DEBUG   :     r0 cdc35980  r1 0000001a  r2 0000001c  r3 fffffffe
03-26 11:23:38.213 24900 24900 F DEBUG   :     r4 cdb7ffe8  r5 d35669e0  r6 cdb7ffec  r7 d317c348
03-26 11:23:38.213 24900 24900 F DEBUG   :     r8 cdedb755  r9 e6ce6fd1  sl d317c300  fp d317d7d4
03-26 11:23:38.213 24900 24900 F DEBUG   :     ip 0000001f  sp d317c280  lr d3495907  pc e1c5a006  cpsr 800d0030
03-26 11:23:38.214 24900 24900 F DEBUG   : 
03-26 11:23:38.214 24900 24900 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
03-26 11:23:38.214 24900 24900 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00000006  <anonymous:e1c5a000>
03-26 11:23:38.214 24900 24900 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000fe903  /data/app/com.attendees-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
03-26 11:23:38.214 24900 24900 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc fffffff9  <unknown>
03-26 11:23:38.593  2798  3358 V AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: Alarm{b9ac566 type 3 when 67906618 com.google.android.gms}operation =Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.location.fused.SEND_LOCATION_IN_SMD_MODE pkg=com.google.android.gms }
03-26 11:23:38.616  4380 18478 W ctxmgr  : [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-1827342116#, com.google.android.gms(10010):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10298000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-1827342116#
03-26 11:23:38.623  4380  6960 W ctxmgr  : [AclManager]No 2 for (accnt=account#-480821402#, com.google.android.gms(10010):UserLocationProducer, vrsn=10298000, 0, 3pPkg = null ,  3pMdlId = null). Was: 2 for 1, account#-480821402#
03-26 11:23:38.862  2798  2835 D DeviceIdleController: handleMessage(6)
03-26 11:23:38.862  2798  2835 D DeviceIdleController: checkTempAppWhitelistTimeout: uid=10010, timeNow=67906887
03-26 11:23:38.862  2798  2835 D DeviceIdleController: Removing UID 10010 from temp whitelist
03-26 11:23:38.862  2798  2835 D DeviceIdleController: Setting wakelock temp whitelist to [10070]
03-26 11:23:38.980  2798 24902 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.attendees/.MainActivity
03-26 11:23:38.982   464   464 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 24853
03-26 11:23:38.976 24904 24904 W coredump.sh: type=1400 audit(0.0:1421): avc: denied { use } for path="pipe:[933531]" dev="pipefs" ino=933531 scontext=u:r:core_dump:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=fd permissive=0
03-26 11:23:38.976 24904 24904 W coredump.sh: type=1400 audit(0.0:1422): avc: denied { use } for path="/system/bin/linker64" dev="dm-0" ino=608 scontext=u:r:core_dump:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=fd permissive=0
03-26 11:23:38.984  2798 24902 D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
03-26 11:23:38.985 24904 24904 F libc    : CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/sh": can't enable GNU RELRO protection for "": Permission denied
03-26 11:23:38.994   579   579 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/24853/oom_score_adj; errno=22
03-26 11:23:39.002  2798 24903 D DropBoxManagerService: file :: /data/system/dropbox/data_app_native_crash@2017-03-26-11_23_38_991.txt
03-26 11:23:39.032  2798  3361 W InputDispatcher: channel '812ef24 com.attendees/com.attendees.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
03-26 11:23:39.032  2798  3361 E InputDispatcher: channel '812ef24 com.attendees/com.attendees.MainActivity (server)' ~ hannel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposedC!
03-26 11:23:39.060  2798  4456 D GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 18
03-26 11:23:39.060  2798  5983 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{812ef24 u0 com.attendees/com.attendees.MainActivity}
03-26 11:23:39.061  2798  5983 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '812ef24 com.attendees/com.attendees.MainActivity (server)'
03-26 11:23:39.062  2798  5983 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.attendees/com.attendees.MainActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2063 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:925 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1465 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2567 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2525 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1796 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:724 <bottom of call stack> 
03-26 11:23:39.062  2798  5986 I ActivityManager: Process com.attendees (pid 24853) has died
03-26 11:23:39.062  2798  5986 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 24853
03-26 11:23:39.087  4717  4717 D Launcher: updateAutoAdvanceState autoAdvanceRunning = false, mAutoAdvanceRunning = false
03-26 11:23:39.087  4717  4717 D RecyclerViewWrapper: onWindowVisibilityChanged:4
03-26 11:23:39.092  4717  4717 D Launcher: onStart
03-26 11:23:39.092  4717  4717 D Launcher: onResume
03-26 11:23:39.095  4717 24906 D AppTracker: App Event: start
03-26 11:23:39.104  4717  4717 D Launcher: updateAutoAdvanceState autoAdvanceRunning = false, mAutoAdvanceRunning = false
03-26 11:23:39.104  4717  4717 D RecyclerViewWrapper: onWindowVisibilityChanged:0
03-26 11:23:39.139  4717  4717 D Launcher.Folder: [RAINN-3245][getItemCount]Office has 3
03-26 11:23:39.661  4717  5029 W OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
03-26 11:23:40.339  2798  2835 D DeviceIdleController: handleMessage(6)
03-26 11:23:40.340  2798  2835 D DeviceIdleController: checkTempAppWhitelistTimeout: uid=10070, timeNow=67908365
03-26 11:23:40.340  2798  2835 D DeviceIdleController: Removing UID 10070 from temp whitelist
03-26 11:23:40.340  2798  2835 D DeviceIdleController: Setting wakelock temp whitelist to []
03-26 11:23:40.990  3536  3764 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 31 -81 -12 202 2147483647 2147483647 4 4 gsm|lte level=4 voicelevel=4 datalevel=4
03-26 11:23:41.003  3536  3764 I NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1):  isDataDisabled:false
03-26 11:23:41.539  2798  2798 I DeviceIdleController: updateChargingLocked: charging=true
03-26 11:23:41.539  2798  2798 I DeviceIdleController: becomeActiveLocked, reason = charging
03-26 11:23:41.543  4411  4521 W QCNEJ   : |CORE| CNE received unexpected action: android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
03-26 11:23:41.546 23281 23366 D HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 10, size: 0
03-26 11:23:41.546 23281 23366 D HeadsetStateMachine: Enter processIntentBatteryChanged()
03-26 11:23:41.546 23281 23366 D HeadsetStateMachine: Exit processIntentBatteryChanged()
03-26 11:23:41.546 23281 23366 D HeadsetStateMachine: Exit Disconnected processMessage() 
03-26 11:23:41.548  4878  4878 D AbstractProcessor: onBatteryChange Percent:32 State:2 
03-26 11:23:41.551  3536  3536 I BatteryController:  fireBatteryLevelChanged mLevel:32 mPluggedIn:true mCharging:true mFastcharge:false
03-26 11:23:41.961  2798  2798 V NotificationService: pkg=com.facebook.orca canInterrupt=false intercept=true
03-26 11:23:41.972  3536  3536 I StatusBarIconView: set mSlot:com.facebook.orca/0x4e21 icon.visible:true mBlocked:false
03-26 11:23:41.980  2798  2798 V NotificationService: pkg=com.facebook.orca canInterrupt=false intercept=true
03-26 11:23:42.016  3536  3536 D PhoneStatusBar: updateMediaMetaData: hasArtwork = true
03-26 11:23:42.016  3536  3536 D StatusBar: onNotificationPosted: end
03-26 11:23:42.016  3536  3536 D PhoneStatusBar: setSystemUiVisibility vis=8 mask=ffffffff oldVal=608 newVal=8 diff=600
03-26 11:23:42.036  3536  3536 D PhoneStatusBar: updateMediaMetaData: hasArtwork = true
03-26 11:23:42.036  3536  3536 D StatusBar: onNotificationPosted: end
03-26 11:23:42.068  3536  3536 D PhoneStatusBar: setSystemUiVisibility vis=608 mask=ffffffff oldVal=8 newVal=608 diff=600
03-26 11:23:42.073  2798  4456 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@67412bd attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b368a88
03-26 11:23:42.266  2798  2798 V NotificationService: pkg=com.facebook.orca canInterrupt=false intercept=true
03-26 11:23:42.273  3536  3536 I StatusBarIconView: set mSlot:com.facebook.orca/0x2710 icon.visible:true mBlocked:false
03-26 11:23:42.335  3536  3536 D PhoneStatusBar: updateMediaMetaData: hasArtwork = true
03-26 11:23:42.335  3536  3536 D StatusBar: onNotificationPosted: end
03-26 11:23:42.863 30729 30729 E msgr.ThreadViewFragment: thread wasn't set before fragment was attached to activity!
03-26 11:23:42.887 30729 30729 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@450e9a6
03-26 11:23:42.887 30729 30729 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@a083fe7
03-26 11:23:42.887 30729 30729 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ca5c794
03-26 11:23:42.887 30729 30729 V BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@5dd423d
03-26 11:23:43.552  3536  3764 D NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 99 0 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 29 -81 -6 218 2147483647 2147483647 4 4 gsm|lte level=4 voicelevel=4 datalevel=4
03-26 11:23:43.563  3536  3764 I NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1):  isDataDisabled:false
03-26 11:23:44.028  5030 24905 W PlatformStatsUtil: Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
```

This is my React component

```
/**
 * Index iOS - Peewah EMS Attendees
 * @author csacanam
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  ListView,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  NetInfo,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  getTheme,
} from 'react-native-material-kit';
import {
  Actions,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';
import EventHeader from '../components/EventHeader';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

const theme = getTheme();
const styles = require('../styles');

class AllEvents extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this._handleFirstConnectivityChange); 
    }
    else {
        NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
          if(isConnected) {
              this.props.setDeviceConnection(true);
              this.props.listAllEvents();
          } else {
            this.props.setDeviceConnection(false);
          }
        });
    }

  }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      NetInfo.removeEventListener('change', this._handleConnectionInfoChange);
  }

  _handleFirstConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {
      if (isConnected) {
        this.props.setDeviceConnection(true);
        this.props.listAllEvents();
      } else {
        this.props.setDeviceConnection(false);
      }
      NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', this._handleFirstConnectivityChange);
  }

  render () {

    if(this.props.allEvents.length > 0) {
        return   (<ListView
                      rowHasChanged={this._rowHasChanged}
                      dataSource = {this.props.allEventsListView}
                      renderRow = { (row, sectionId, rowId) => 
                      <View style={[theme.cardStyle, {marginTop: rowId == 0 ? 0:10}]}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                          onPress = { () => {
                            this.props.setCurrentEvent(row);
                            this.props.setCurrentEventRow(rowId);
                            Actions.eventDetail();
                          }}>
                          <EventHeader event={row} row={rowId}/>
                          <View style={{ padding : 15}}>
                            <Text style={[customStyles.container, {color: row.fontColor} ]}>{row.name}</Text>
                            <Text style={[theme.cardContentStyle, {padding:0}]}>
                              {row.place}{"\n"}{moment(row.startDate).format('ll')}
                            </Text>
                          </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      </View>}/>);      
    }
    else if ( !this.props.isDeviceConnected ) {
      return (<View style={customStyles.centerView}><Text style={customStyles.noInternetConnectionTitle}>No tienes conexión a Internet</Text></View>);
    }
    else {
      return (<View style={customStyles.centerView}><Progress.Circle size={30} indeterminate={true} /></View>);
    }

  }

}

var customStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  centerView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  noInternetConnectionTitle: {
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: 18,
}
});



function mapStateToProps( state ) {
  return {
    allEvents: state.listAllPublicEvents,
    allEventsListView: ds.cloneWithRows(state.listAllPublicEvents),
    isDeviceConnected: state.setDeviceConnection,
  }
}

const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
});



AppRegistry.registerComponent('AllEvents', () => AllEvents);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AllEvents);
```

Comment: dude, your logcat doesn't show anything related to your app. after connecting to your phone, can you filter the results, showing only app related outputs?

Comment: @EnieJakiro I'm sorry. I'll do that and paste it here.

Comment: @EnieJakiro I just update the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days I figure it out it was a leak memory error related with the library I was using to show a progress bar before fetching the web service. It was this library (https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress). Now I'm using this one (https://github.com/bgryszko/react-native-circular-progress) and everything is working fine.